# Not able to Install and run test chaincode on AWS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am following this tutorial [Link](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/ce1e960e-a811-475f-a221-2afcf57e386a/en-US/02-set-up-a-fabric-client/05-configure-client/08-install-and-run-chaincode). I am getting this error.
Error Error: could not assemble transaction, ***err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy***

How can I fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue

I deleted the admin cert and enrolled the fabric admin again, so that the old cert which was used to create the channel "mainchannel" was lost so that I cannot upgrade the channel chain code anymore.

Every time I instantiated or upgraded the chaincode, I received the error: err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy

Finally, I have to create new channel